# Problem with TCP server in Twisted

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

I'm trying to make a simple TCP server using Twisted ,which can do some interaction between diffirent client connections.The main code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from time import ctime

#global variables
PORT = 22334
connlist = {}    #store all the connections
ids = {}    #map the from-to relationships

class TSServerProtocol(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        from_id,to_id = data.split('|') #get the IDs from standard client input,which looks like "from_id|to_id"

        if self.haveConn(from_id):    #try to store new connections' informations
            pass
        else:
            self.setConn(from_id)
            self.setIds(from_id,to_id) 

        if to_id in self.csids.keys():                 
             self.connlist[to_id].transport.write(\
             "you get a message now!from %s \n" % from_id)    #if the to_id target found,push him a message.doesn't work as expected
    def setConn(self,sid):
        connlist[sid] = self

    #some other functions

factory = protocol.Factory()
factory.protocol = TSServerProtocol
print 'waiting from connetction...'
reactor.listenTCP(PORT, factory)
reactor.run()
```

As the comments mentioned,if a new client connection comes,I'll store its connection handle in  a global varaible `connlist` which is like

```
connlist = {a_from_id:a_conObj,b_from_id:b_conObj,....}
```

and also parse the input then map its from-to information in `ids`.Then I check whether there's a key in the `ids` matches current "to_id".if does,get the connection handle using `connlist[to_id]` and push a message to the target connection.But it doesn't work.The message only shows in a same connection.Hope someone can show me some directions about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `dataReceived` function is referencing a local `self.connlist`, not the global. Don't use globals. You may want to store the conn list on the factory instance and access it from a protocol instance via `self.factory.connlist`

Comment: @MattH,thank you for the note.would you tell me which object should I store in `connlist` if i do this in factory?

Comment: It would be great if you could come up with a better title for this question, something that points at a bit more specifically what you're trying to ask.  Other people also have similar questions, and that would help them find it when searching.  Way too many SO Twisted questions are titled just "problem with Twisted" or "Twisted broken, need help" or "help with Twisted", et cetera.

Comment: @Glyph,well nice tip.Actually evertime I feel difficult to make a short description for a problem I use some titles like this one...Probably I should improve my halfcooked english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time a TCP connection is made, Twisted will create a unique instance of `TSServerProtocol` to handle that connection. So, you'll only ever see 1 connection in `TSServerProtocol`. Normally, this is what you want but Factories can be extended to do the connection tracking you're attempting to do here. Specifically, you can subclass `Factory` and override the buildProtocol() method to track instances of `TSServerProtocol`. The interrelationship between all the classes in Twisted takes a little time to learn and get used to. In particular, this piece of the [standard Twisted documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html) should be your best friend for the next while ;-)

Comment: Thanks for nice suggestion.I'm trying to handle it better:)